# Nodejs async: How to map keys to key-values?

Tags: node.js, node-async

I can't to find a method of async.js library for followed:

I have:

- keys array `['a', 'b', 'c']`
- iterator like:

```
    function it(item, next){
      next(null, item+item);
    }
```

If I use `async.map([1, 5], it, cb)`, I get `[2, 10]`.

How can I get `{ 1: 2, 5: 10 }` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some variations:

```
// #1
async.map(keys, function(key, next) {
  someFoo(key, function(err, value) {
    // TODO: handle err, or not.
    next(null, value);
  });
}, function(err, result) {
  var finalresult = {};
  keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
    finalresult[key] = result[i];
  });
  cb(err, finalresult);
});

// #2
async.parallel((function() {
  var actions = {};
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    actions[key] = function(next) {
      someFoo(key, function(err, value) {
        // TODO: handle err, or not.
        next(null, value);
      });
    };
  });
  return actions;
})(), function(err, results) {
  cb(err, finalresult);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution:

```
var result = {}
async.each(keys, function(key, next){
  someFoo(key, function(err, value){
    if(err) 'ignore error';
    result[key] = value;
    next();
  })
}, function(err){
 cb(err, result)
})
```

Have anyone more beauty solution?

*I think about there is not universal solution, because even here all crashes if keys includes noscalar values.*

Answer (score 0):

A little more elegant using [reduce](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#reduce)

```
async.reduce([1, 2, 3], {}, function(memo, item, callback) {
  memo[item] = item + item;
  cb(err, memo);
}, function(err, result) {
  cb(err, result)
});
```

**Untested code*